# Picture follow a mouse in a <div>

Tags: javascript

How can I make a picture follow the mouse in a specific `<div>`?

I know that I can get the mouse position from `e.pageX & e.pageY` and with the code `document.onmousemove = followmouse;`. Run the `followmouse` function every moment the mouse move in a page and in the `followmouse` function, set the picture position to the mouse position. For the exact question I asked here (how can I make a picture follow the mouse in a specific `<div>`), I have this idea:

Get my div *top*, *left*, *width*, and *height* and do some math and if mouse go out of the `div`, set `visibility:hidden` for the picture.

But isn't there any simple way to do this?

Comment: It's called a tooltip, and jquery and mootools have a lot of plugins to do various things with tooltips.

Comment: @Marc are there any **javascript** sample code ? i don't want use jquery. and where can i find those tooltip

Comment: jquery and mootools ARE javascript. They're just helper libraries, and they'd be the simplest method of doing what you want. They handle all the stupid browser incompatibilities for you. If you want to roll your own tooltip library, go ahead, but you'll be wasting a lot of time getting it to work in every browser.

Comment: i know they are, but i need more speed functions and some times jquery is not a good one

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have some [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) like this,

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<img id="myimg" style="position: absolute;" alt="" />
```

then

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onmousemove = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("myimg").style.top = e.pageY*1 + 5 + "px";
    document.getElementById("myimg").style.left = e.pageX*1 + 5 + "px";
}
```

would move your picture to the mouse only if the mouse is over the `div`.

Comment: i couldn't run your codes ? picture don't move. and can you explain meaning of `e.pageY*1 + 5 + "px"`

Comment: @hamze you can try my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/j7eMz/

The part you ask means: X coordinate of mouse multiplied by 1 to ensure it is an integer, than add 5 for a little distance from the mouse, and finally the "px", since style.left accepts values with some unit.

Comment: it's wired, when i add your code to a `htm` file image doesn't move  and i got this error : `document.getElementById("mydiv") is null`

Comment: @hamze `"mydiv"` is the `id` of the `div` in my example. You have to change it to the `id` of your `div`. Same goes with `"myimg"`. Also, this javascript code must run after the your `div` was created in the page.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the picture is actually contained in the `div` and you move it relative to its normal position, then I think setting `overflow:hidden` on the containing `div` should work. When I say "setting", I don't mean every time the mouse moves outside, but just once in the main [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).